# Pygame: Some of my sprites are getting stuck on the right side of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

My game is almost complete! Unfortunately, there are some little details I need to fix. The main one is that after you play for a bit, some of the sprites will get stuck on the front of the screen. Can anybody please help me out.

```
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
X = 400
Y = 400
SCREEN_WIDTH = display_width
SCREEN_HEIGHT = display_height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

def death():
    global alive
    print('You died')
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You Died.', False, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))
    

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Missile.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 1
            self.kill()

class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bomb, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Bomber.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 2
            self.kill()

class Blimp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Blimp, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 35))
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Blimp.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            global score
            score += 3
            self.kill()

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 950)

player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bomb = pygame.sprite.Group()
blimp = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False

        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_enemy = Enemy()
            new_bomb = Bomb()
            new_blimp = Blimp()
            spawn = random.randint(1,3)
            if spawn == 1:
                enemies.add(new_enemy)
            if spawn == 2:
                enemies.add(new_blimp)
            if spawn == 3:
                enemies.add(new_bomb)
            all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_bomb)
            all_sprites.add(new_blimp)

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((50,50,160))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        alive = False
        death()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Press the arrow keys to move. The text box (not in the new window) will tell you your score.

[image: This is the blimp file]
[image: This is the bomb(er) file]
[image: This is the enemy (missile) file]
[image: This is the plane file]

Comment: OK, I will do that.

Comment: do you get an error, or you just have this issue during the game?

Comment: There are some typos: `Groupp()` -> `Group()`, `blimp()` -> `Blimp()`

Comment: It does not give me an error. It just makes some of the objects freeze before they enter the screen, making it so that you can see the tip of the plane/blimp/missile on the right side of the screen.

Comment: @RhinoRunner I got this error when i tried running your code.                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test.py", line 126, in <module>
    player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)
  File "C:/test.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.surf = pygame.image.load("Plane.png").convert()
pygame.error: Couldn't open Plane.png

Comment: I guess i need that png file or i'll just add a different one.

Comment: OK I put the Piskel pictures onto the question.

Comment: @RhinoRunner I'll just use different ones to test the game

Comment: @RhinoRunner i got this error when trying to run it. line 144, in <module>
    new_blimp = blimp()
TypeError: 'Group' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update all the enemies which are on the *Group* `enemies`

> ```py
> enemies.update()
> ```

And you draw all the *Sprites* in the group `all_sprites`.

> ```py
> for entity in all_sprites:
>    screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)
> ```

But not all enemies which are in the *Group* `all_sprites` are in the *Group* `enemies`, too:

> ```py
> new_enemy = Enemy()
> new_bomb = Bomb()
> new_blimp = Blimp()
> spawn = random.randint(1,3)
> if spawn == 1:
>    enemies.add(new_enemy)
> if spawn == 2:
>    enemies.add(new_blimp)
> if spawn == 3:
>    enemies.add(new_bomb)
> all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
> all_sprites.add(new_bomb)
> all_sprites.add(new_blimp)
> ```

All the enemies which are in the *Group* `all_sprites`, but not in the *Group* `enemies` are drawn but don't move.

Create a random enemy type and add it to both *Gourps*:

```py
alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False

        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            
            new_opponent = random.choice([Enemy(), Bomb(), Blimp()])
            enemies.add(new_opponent)
            all_sprites.add(new_opponent)
```

Comment: OK, so with this in the code it works, but then I cannot change the rate at which they spawn. Normally, I would use this line of code (line ~123) "pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 850)"and when I increase the integer, the amount of time before the enemies spawn is increased. Is there any way that I could do something like that in my code?

Comment: @RhinoRunner Invoke `pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, random.randrange(800, 1200))` in `elif event.type == ADDENEMY:`